# Use look up to find the values in xml , xsl

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am new to this Technology. I need to use the lookup concept here,

I have a XML file: As below,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="lookup.xsl"?>

    <member>

            <name>Indhu</name>
            <pir>PIR1</pir>
            <age>25</age>
            <novel>Nothing hides</novel>
            <script>Hello you </script>

    </member>
```

The xsl file is:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
          <html>
         <head>
         <title>YOU</title>
         </head>
         <body>

         <h1>Hello world</h1>
         <div name="test">
         <table border="0">

         <tr><td><xsl:value-of select="member/name" /></td></tr>
         <tr><td><xsl:value-of select="member/age" /></td></tr> 
         <tr>
         <td>PIR Rate: </td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="member/pir"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="pircode_lookup">
                <xsl:with-param name="pircode" select="pirCode" />
                </xsl:call-template>
              </td>
              </tr>

              </table>
              </div>
              </body> 
              </html>
               </xsl:template>
             </xsl:transform>
```

I have a lookupValues xsl file :

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
         xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">


         <xsl:template name="pircode_lookup">
         <xsl:param name="pircode"/>
         <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$pircode='PIR0'">
            <xsl:text>Zero</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$pircode='PIR1'">
            <xsl:text>One</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$pircode='PIR2'">
            <xsl:text>Two</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$pircode='PIR3'">
            <xsl:text>Three</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$pircode='PIRD'">
            <xsl:text>Default</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text>Unknown PIR Code: </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="pirCode"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

I want this call to access the lookupValues.xsl and get me the value of PIR1, but i am getting the default value as result (Unknown PIR code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time when you call the `pircode_lookup` template, you are at the root node want to pass the `member/pir` node as the `$pircode` param. So:

```
<xsl:with-param name="pircode" select="member/pir" />
```

---

You also wrote `pirCode` one time, when you should have written `$pircode` in your `<xsl:choose>`:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$pircode='PIR0'">Zero</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$pircode='PIR1'">One</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$pircode='PIR2'">Two</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$pircode='PIR3'">Three</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$pircode='PIRD'">Default</xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>Unknown PIR Code: <xsl:value-of select="$pircode"/></xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Note: You can work with `<xsl:text>`, this is absolutely correct to avoid unwanted whitespace in the output.

However as long as you don't have any unnecessary whitespace in the XSL, you can compress the code a bit by dropping the `<xsl:text>`, like shown above.

Comment: Thank you. Done :) Actually am new here

Comment: I know, that's why I gave the hint. Generally on this site, you don't need to accept an answer immediately - it's fine to wait if better answers come. But when there is an answer that exactly solves the problem, it's fair to mark it as accepted it at some point.